# Why was my accepted answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, deleted-answers, users, moderators

I commented on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209066/2886003). The user commented back saying it solved the problem. Another user warned about my comment. I posted an answer and got it marked as accepted, but I got the answer deleted by a moderator.

I suspect it is due to a flag of a user who disagrees with my solution.

What should I have done (if I should do anything)?

Comment: It was there, but I don't want to drag the meta effect to the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your answer was a question:

> Which python version do you have? Update the python version to 2.7 or greater. It is strange that the module argparse isn't found.

From the flag queue that looked awfully much like a comment and not an answer, which is probably why it was flagged in the first place. You even had the exact same text as a comment on the post.

Now that you've edited it I undeleted the post.

Answer (score 5):

> What should I have done (If I should do something)?

You should have written it **as an answer**, rather than copying the comment verbatim. Presumably, it was flagged as NAA - looking at the *answer in isolation*, can you see why Martijn would have concurred with that assessment?

Comment: I can't see why Martijn would have concurred with that assessment : "deleted by Martijn Pieters♦ 22 hours ago
Why was your post deleted? See the help center."

Comment: @Llopis you *"can't"* what?

Comment: @Llopis: you can't undelete it your self. But you can edit. And once it actually looks like an answer, flag it for moderator attention and ask for it to be undeleted.

Comment: @Llopis really? It comprises three sentences: a question, a suggestion and a comment. None explain what the problem is, or offer any certainty that upgrading *is* the fix.